# Regex как разделить строку на цифры и буквы

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть строки такого типа:

```
МАП 50-00, МАП 50-02, КАТ 12582365, КРТВ 123456, саа123456 (Аввв) и т.п.
```

как с помощью регулярки можно разделить строки на цифры и буквы
в данном случае символ `(-)` должен входить в числа

```
МАП
50-00

МАП
50-02

КАТ 
12582-365

КРТВ 
123456

саа
123456
```

Пробовал `(\D) (\d+-*) (\d+) ([\D]\D)`
не один вариант не подошёл, все варианты работают частично.

Возможно ли так сделать?

Comment: если они такого типа то можно разделить сначала по \n\n строку затем спокойно по \n и не думать о числах и буквах

Comment: @Aziz Umarov не всегда есть пробел

Comment: ясно, просто я стараюсь подвесит под стандарт и тупо делю на подстроки. Тем самым проверяю валидность входных данных

Comment: @Aziz Umarov В том то и дело что стандарта нет (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
([А-ЯЁа-яёA-Za-z]+)\s?(\d+(?:-\d+)?)
```

первая группа `([А-ЯЁа-яёA-Za-z]+)` - обязательно один и более буквенных символов
`\s?` - ноль или один пробельный символ
`(\d+(?:-\d+)?)` - одна и более цифра, с необязательной группой `-`одна и более цифра

пример: https://regex101.com/r/mZuHlw/1/

---

Что бы можно было выбрать текст из нескольких слов

```
([А-ЯЁа-яё]+(?:\s[А-ЯЁа-яё]+)*)\s?(\d+(?:-\d+)?)
```

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/mZuHlw/2

Comment: Огромное спасибо! А, не подскажешь возможно ли в проверку вставить проверку на что то подобное `Вот такая строка пример 552-017` вытаскивает только `пример 552-017`?

Comment: @EugeneTM дополнил ответ

Comment: Начал тестировать, немного изменил по ходу дела выражение `([А-ЯA-ZЁа-яёa-z]+(?:\s*[А-ЯA-ZЁа-яёa-z]+)*?:*)\s?\s?(\d+(?:-\d+)?)`, но наткнулся ещё на такую строчку `ККК 50-31/А` не как не пойму, как добавить к цифрам `/A` да и на слеш ругается, не подскажешь как можно добавить? Перепробовал несколько вариантов но не как (

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/mZuHlw/4 - тут пример и соответственно весь шаблон, еще одну необязательную группу добавить `(?:\/[А-ЯЁа-яё0-9])?`, а слеш нужно экранировать обратным слешем, либо в выражение использовать иной разделитель(поддерживается вроде как не во всех языках)

Answer (score 4):

Предлагаю использовать [категории юникода](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories). В частности, `L` означает любую букву в любом алфавите. Благодаря этому шаблон регулярки получается лаконичным (и понятным).

```
string input = "МАП 50-00, МАП 50-02, КАТ 12582365, КРТВ 123456, саа123456";            
string pattern = @"(\p{L}+)\s*([\d-]+)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```